# Web app feels less responsive when added to iPhone's home screen

Tags: ios, angular, progressive-web-apps

This Angular 2 app feels less responsive when added to the Home Screen on the iPhone that when running inside Safari.

I made it web app capable by adding this to index.html:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Angular NavTabs">
```

If you have a couple of minutes, [check it out on Github Pages](https://cmermingas.github.io/angular-tab-nav/).

Switching between tabs feel very responsive when it runs in Safari. However, it feels lagging when the app is launched from the Home Screen.

**Is there something that I could change in or add to the code to fix this behavior?**

Note: The same thing happens if I remove the animations from the app.

I recorded a couple of animated GIFs to try to show the difference but it's difficult to appreciate unless you're actually interacting with the app.

[image: App running in Safari]

[image: App running from Home Screen]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're experiencing the infamous "[300ms seconds delay](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/what-exactly-is.....-the-300ms-click-delay)", which was fixed for quite some time in Safari Mobile, but still here once your app is added to the home screen.

Using the [FastClick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) library should solve the problem.

To use it in an Angular application, install the npm package:

`npm install --save fastclick`

Then add this to your `main.ts` file:

```
import * as fastClick from 'fastclick';
fastClick.attach(document.body);
```

**Edit**:

With iOS 11, web-apps added to the home sreen will now be hosted in a WKWebView instead of UIWebView, which will make use of FastClick obsolete: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Safari_11_0/Safari_11_0.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: For clarity, upgrading to iOS 11 seemed to fix the issue (by removing the 300ms delay). I didn't need to add FastClick.

Comment: Could it be that this issue is back? I'm certainly still experiencing this!