# Improve response time on mobile device for angular 2 (300ms)

Tags: angular

I have created a very basic app with angular 2 + angular CLI + ngbootstrap. There is only two dropdowns in the app. However, I am finding that when I use my mobile device, there seems to be some sort of delay between when I click the button and when the dropdown appears. I believe this is the famous 300ms delay? Because when I tap slightly quicker (even on the button), the app zooms in on my iphone.

I am not 100% sure if this actually is the 300ms delay because according to [Google's View On 300ms Delay](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/12/300ms-tap-delay-gone-away), my angular project comes with the default setting to turn it off because I found the following code inside my index.html file

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

So the question is:

Is this delay 300ms delay. If yes, why is it not turned off?. If no? what delay is this and how/if I can improve it so it feels more closer to a native app? I do find that when I use my computer to view the webpage, the button responses alot faster.

Here is a link to the app [myTestApp](http://angular2-deploy-2.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/)

And here is the source code [Github source](https://github.com/eddy80310/testApp)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend removing the 300ms delay and seeing if it solves your issue (I'd bet it does). You can install [fastclick.js](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) and remove the 300ms delay in about 10secs as a proof of concept.

Checkout the answer posted below:

[Web app feels less responsive when added to iPhone's home screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39902055/web-app-feels-less-responsive-when-added-to-iphones-home-screen)